# Pass a Date to a LWC, convert it, and submit it back to Salesforce

Tags: lightning-web-components, datetime

In this example the Start Date is update via the UI of a LWC.

End Date is not displayed in the UI

**How do we get the End Date updated so the duration stays the same
Ultimately we seems to be struggling with the JS Date format and the SF Format
But the JSON suggests it is OK**

this line of code seems to be the problem:

fields.custom_End_Date_Field__c = this.date3;

```
onSubmitHandler(event){
    let fields = event.detail.fields;
    this.date1 = new Date(fields.custom_End_Date_Field__c);
    this.date2 = new Date(fields.custom_Start_Date_Field__c);
    this.oldDuration = thisDate1-thisDate2;

    //(custom_Start_Date_Field__c updated via HTML field)

    this.date3 = new Date(fields.custom_Start_Date_Field__c);
    this.date3.setMilliseconds(this.date3.getMilliseconds() + this.oldDuration);
    fields.custom_End_Date_Field__c = this.date3;
    window.console.log('After '+JSON.stringify(fields));
    this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to cancel the default submission, which could be causing your problem. Try adding `event.preventDefault()` at the top of your method.

Comment: You could assign this.date3.toISOString() which converts from js date to string like `2022-03-10T17:18:51.884Z`